# Online, free SMILES interpreter

Tags: structural-formula

A while back, I used [chemspider.com](http://www.chemspider.com/) at some point to get structures from a SMILES string. I found that it wouldn't get some strings, so I switched to [chemicalize.org](http://www.chemicalize.org/). The site appears to have been taken over and doesn't read SMILES strings anymore. I found [this site](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure) in this [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/43301), but yet again there are some strings it won't read.

I want to do a SMILES demonstration in a comp lab, so I'd rather have a website instead of having to install a program. Is there any online, free SMILES interpreter?

Edit: I'm looking for an entirely online, no-install-required translator.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://jacobdurrant.com/2014/05/20/online-smiles-string-to-3d-visualizer/) site?

Comment: Assuming you need the structures for further computations, consider openbabel (http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: @airhuff I like that visualizator, but it doesn't like salts or stereochemistry, nor gives the name of the molecule.

Comment: @DSVA I am looking for an entirely online solution.

Comment: @Buttonwood Not right now but I'll have a look for further use.

Comment: @Kurzd For structure <-> SMILES, this Marvin js demo (as in Elsevier's Reaxys) may be something: https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/demo.html  Does however not offer the structure -> name conversion you aim for.

Comment: @Kurzd the first two answers in the linked post got both a solution which is entirely online. And if it's a comp lab I really don't understand why it would be a problem to use actual software. All you need is a server (even a raspberry would do it), throw open babel and jmol or pymol on that and you are done. Structure to name is a whole different beast.

Comment: @Buttonwood Marvin will do for now :D. It's from the company that took over chemicalize.org, so I hope it stays available for a long time.

Comment: @DSVA Installing software is a hassle, and the Cactus site is cumbersome. The raspberry suggestion is neat but it's impossible for me to do it.

Comment: Go to chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=["ENTER SMILES HERE"]

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I tried with linear and cyclic molecules, but all I got was a pink sphere and seemingly no way to rotate it. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kurzd I get that installing software might be cumbersome, but openbabel is extremly easy to install on both windows and linux and it can produce pngs of SMILES extremly easy. It's also an very helpful program if you ever deal with any kind of 3D structures. And I'm really wondering what kind of comp lab doesn't have the opportunity to have software installed on the clients or on a linux server (you can use the open babel method from command line, you don't even need X-server)

Comment: @DSVA I'd have to make a request for software to be installed. I've requested TeX Live twice, but nothing has happened. As far as I know there's no linux server either. I'll suggest open babel to my classmates in case they want to do some testing on their own computers.

Comment: @Kurzd TeXLive has a portable version. You can set it up yourself assuming your PC isn't designed to reset at every logon. (Similar to steady state in the past.)

Comment: And here is another website that understands SMILES: http://rmg.mit.edu/molecule_search